# Google Sheets: Is it possible to retain an IF/ELSE formula *AND* enable custom number entry into a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm using the IF/ELSE formula in a cell:

`=IF(logical_expression, "TRUE", "")`

My use case is the following:

- If the `logical_expression` is `TRUE`: A logic-derived value is shown in the cell to the user, but
- If the `logical_expression is` `""`: I want the user to enter a (custom) value themselves into the empty cell – without removing the formula

Is it possible to have this cell take both options? Or do I need to set this up across multiple cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any cell or range can hold *either* a formula *or* hard-coded data, not both.

If you want both, then you'll have to use drag-down type formulas in each cell of the range where you want both. The formula will show its results until when/if someone selects that cell and types into it (at which time the formula will no longer exist in that cell and will have been replaced with the manually entered data). However, setting up a sheet this way for regular use by users is virtually guaranteed to wind up with big problems (e.g., what if a user deletes the formula from the wrong cell and then can't get it back the way it was? What if they change their mind and want the formula result back? etc.).

It's best to share a link to a spreadsheet explaining your *full context*. There may be other suggestions that can be made if the volunteer contributors here have all the details about actual use.

Comment: Answered perfectly, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. One suggestion: you could make your `FALSE` value something like "Enter custom value" (or even "Enter custom value to the right >>>"). In the first case, the person would be prompted by the formula in that cell to type into the cell (which as I said above, will delete the formula). The second option would prompt them to type their custom value in the *next cell over*. If you choose this option, you could use one array formula for the formula column, no dragging down. Feel free to share a link to a spreadsheet if you want to see what I mean.

Comment: Like a validation column! Great idea, thanks!